# input type date and input type time are not showing their corresponding icons nor their default placeholders on mobile the input is simply blank

Tags: html, input, mobile

Input type date and input type time are not showing their corresponding icons nor their default placeholders on mobile the input is simply blank, however, their pickers are working.
They all work on desktop and it shows if I select a mobile device on chrome developer tools.
my code:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-xl-2 col-xl-4">

    <label for="insessiondate" class="col-md-12 col-form-label labelSpace2">Session Date*</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="insessiondate" name="insessiondate" area-describedby="sessiondate" required="true">

</div>  
    
    
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">

    <label for="insessiontime" class="col-md-12 col-form-label labelSpace2">Session Time*</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" id="insessiontime" name="insessiontime" area-describedby="sessiontime" required="true">
      
</div>
```

As you can see I am using bootstrap if that might have something to do with the problem.

Comment: Aren't those icons browser specific? MacOS Safari doesn't display them like Chrome or Edge do.

Comment: They are not showing at all on chrome mobile nor on safari mobile, is this their default behavior? to be blank.

Comment: Yes, I think you're testing one browser and expect all browsers out there to behave the same way. Browsers offer a default style for date/time inputs as a UI choice, but there's no HTML/CSS standard for those. If you want the same style across all browsers, you'll have to design your own.